# Bearer Authentication in Python

Tags: python, api, authentication

I am running into a problem trying to rewrite the bearer authentication in Python from Java for the IronSource API. This is the code I am trying to replicate:

```
$authURL = 'https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth';
$authHeaders = array(
        'secretkey: <e83defbasdasd9227a9d2a952b2c5ec8b02e>',
        'refreshToken: <ee453860sd9227a9d2a952b2c5e476iii3gh5>',
);

$curlClient = curl_init($authURL);
curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $authHeaders);
curl_setopt($curlClient, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$bearerTokenResponse = curl_exec($curlClient);
$bearerToken = str_replace('"','',$bearerTokenResponse);
curl_close($curlClient);
```

It seems like this should be very straightforward to pass the secretkey and refreshtoken that I have on the website, but my attempts keep failing. Here is what I have tried:

```
import requests

class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r

response = requests.get('https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth', auth=BearerAuth('INSERT SECRET KEY HERE'))
```

And Also this!

`import requests
endpoint = "https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth"

#### No Idea what data I am supposed to be posting here

data = {"ip": "1.1.2.3"}

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer MYSECRETKEY"}

print(requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers).json())`

According to the IronSource website, I am expecting the bearer AUTH to be returned, and then I need to do another get request with the AuthHeader having the bearer token in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `IronSource` [documentation](https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/air/authentication/#step-1), two Authentications.

[image]

#### #1 Bearer API Authentication

curl command

```
curl --silent --location 'https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth' \
--header 'secretkey: <your secret key>' \
--header 'refreshToken: <your refresh token>'
```

Result
[image]

Python code

```py
import requests

url='https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth'
headers = {
    'secretkey': '<your secret key>',
    'refreshToken': '<your refresh token>'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(response.content)
```

Result
[image]

#### #2 Standard API Authentication

Simular but you needs to add more information

```
curl --silent --location 'https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth' \
--header 'secretkey: <your secret-key>' \
--header 'refreshToken: <your refresh token>' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic '$(base64 <<<"<your user name>:<your secret-key>")
```

Result
[image]

Python Code

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url='https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/publisher/auth'
headers = {
    'secretkey': '<your secret key>',
    'refreshToken': '<your refresh token>'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, auth= HTTPBasicAuth('<your user name>', '<your secret-key>'))
print(response.content)
```

Result
[image]

*Note : ,  and 
Get from your account dash board.

```
https://platform.ironsrc.com/partners/account/apiDetails
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is awesome thanks! It got me what I was looking for and then it was easy enough to add in the additional GET request once I had the bearer Authentication to get the data pull!

Comment: @TFunk, I am happy to hear you got it.